# Theorem 4, Section 5.4 of Hoffman’s Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification, proof-writing, determinant

> Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ matrix over $K$. Then $A$ is invertible over $K$ if and only if $\text{det}(A)$ is invertible in $K$. When $A$ is invertible, the unique inverse for $A$ is $$A^{-l}=(\text{det}(A))^{-1} \text{adj}(A).$$ In particular, an $n\times n$ matrix over a field is invertible if and only if its determinant is different from zero.

**My attempt:** $(\Rightarrow)$ Suppose $A$ is invertible over $K$. Then $\exists !\ A^{-1}\in M_{n\times n}(K)$ such that $AA^{-1}=A^{-1}A=I_n$. So $\text{det}(AA^{-1})= \text{det}(A^{-1}A)= \text{det}(I_n)= 1_K$. By theorem 3 section 5.3, $\text{det}(A)\cdot \text{det}(A^{-1})= \text{det}(A^{-1})\cdot \text{det}(A)=1_K$. Thus $\text{det}(A^{-1})\in K$ is inverse of $\text{det}(A)$, i.e. $\text{det}(A^{-1})= (\text{det}(A))^{-1}$. Hence $\text{det}(A)$ is invertible in $K$. $(\Leftarrow)$ Conversely suppose $\text{det}(A)$ is invertible in $K$. Then $\exists !\ (\text{det}(A))^{-1}\in K$ such that $\text{det}(A)\cdot (\text{det}(A))^{-1}=(\text{det}(A))^{-1}\cdot \text{det}(A)=1_K$. Since $A\cdot \text{adj}(A)= \text{det}(A)\cdot I_n$, we have $(\text{det}(A))^{-1}\cdot A\cdot \text{adj}(A)= (\text{det}(A))^{-1}\cdot  \text{det}(A)\cdot I_n=I_n$. Since $\text{adj}(A) \cdot A= \text{det}(A)\cdot I_n$, we have $(\text{det}(A))^{-1}\cdot \text{adj}(A)\cdot A= (\text{det}(A))^{-1}\cdot  \text{det}(A)\cdot I_n=I_n$. Thus $A\cdot [(\text{det}(A))^{-1}\text{adj}(A)]=[(\text{det}(A))^{-1}\text{adj}(A)]\cdot A=I_n$. Hence $A^{-1}= (\text{det}(A))^{-1}\text{adj}(A)$. So $A$ is invertible over $K$.

We claim, $\text{det}(A)$ is invertible in $F$$\iff$$\text{det}(A)\neq 0_F$. Proof: $(\Rightarrow)$ Suppose $\text{det}(A)$ is invertible in $F$. Then $\exists !\ (\text{det}(A))^{-1}\in F$ such that $\text{det}(A)\cdot (\text{det}(A))^{-1}=1_F$. Assume towards contradiction, $\text{det}(A)=0_F$. So $\text{det}(A)\cdot (\text{det}(A))^{-1}=0_F=1_F$. Thus we reach contradiction. Hence $\text{det}(A)\neq 0_F$. $(\Leftarrow)$ Conversely suppose $\text{det}(A)\neq 0_F$. By definition of field, $\exists !\ (\text{det}(A))^{-1}\in F$ such that $\text{det}(A)\cdot (\text{det}(A))^{-1}=1_F$. Hence $\text{det}(A)$ is invertible in $F$. **Is my proof correct?**

**Edit:** I missed one detail in the proof. If $c\in K$ and $A,B\in M_n(K)$, then $c\cdot(AB)=(c\cdot A)B=A(c\cdot B)$. Proof: $[c\cdot(AB)]_{ij}=c\cdot(AB)_{ij}=c\cdot\sum_kA_{ik}B_{kj}=\sum_kc\cdot(A_{ik}B_{kj})$, by distributive property of ring $K$. Since $K$ is commutative & associative, we have $c\cdot(A_{ik}B_{kj})= (c\cdot A_{ik})B_{kj}=A_{ik}(c\cdot B_{kj})$. So $\sum_kc\cdot(A_{ik}B_{kj})=\sum_k (c\cdot A_{ik})B_{kj}=[(c\cdot A)B]_{ij}$ and $\sum_kc\cdot(A_{ik}B_{kj})=\sum_k A_{ik}(c\cdot B_{kj})=[A(c\cdot B)]_{ij}$. Thus $[c\cdot(AB)]_{ij}= [(c\cdot A)B]_{ij}=[A(c\cdot B)]_{ij}$, for all $(i,j)\in J_n\times J_n$. Hence $c\cdot(AB)=(c\cdot A)B=A(c\cdot B)$.

This completes the detail of $(\text{det}(A))^{-1}\cdot A\cdot \text{adj}(A)= A\cdot [(\text{det}(A))^{-1}\text{adj}(A)]$ and $(\text{det}(A))^{-1}\cdot \text{adj}(A)\cdot A= [(\text{det}(A))^{-1}\text{adj}(A)]\cdot A$.

Comment: Your approach is fine (in a commutative ring $K$, I suppose?). The special case for fields can be immediately written by noting the only noninvertible element is zero, hence the only noninvertible matrices are those with zero determinant. The 'one detail' you missed is a very elementary detail, so I haven't bothered to check you did it correctly - and I don't think anyone else would, ordinarily. You can definitely write proofs and omit details like that! (lord knows, many textbook / article authors have a habit of writing complex proofs whilst omitting details very nonobvious to the student)

Comment: @FShrike yes I agree, that detail is really elementary.