# Exercise 9, Section 6.6 of Hoffman’s Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, proof-writing, determinant, projection

> Let $V$ be a real vector space and $E$ an idempotent linear operator on $V$, i.e., a projection. Prove that $(I + E)$ is invertible. Find $(I + E)^{-1}$.

**My attempt:** Suppose $E:V\to V$ be a projection. Then $V=R_E\oplus N_E$. Let $B_1=\{\alpha_1,…,\alpha_r\}$ and $B_2=\{\alpha_{r+1},…,\alpha_n\}$ be basis of $R_E$ and $N_E$, respectively. So $B=B_1\cup B_2=\{\alpha_1,…,\alpha_n\}$ is basis of $V$ and $[E]_B=\begin{bmatrix}I_r&0 \\ 0&0\\ \end{bmatrix}$, where $I_r\in M_{r\times r}(\Bbb{R})$ is identity and $r\geq 0$. By [exercise 6 section 5.4](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4553308/861687), $(I+E)$ is invertible$\iff$$\det (I+E)\neq 0$. So $$\det (I+E)=\det ([I+E]_B)=\det ([I]_B+[E]_B)=\det \left(I_n+\begin{bmatrix} I_r&0 \\ 0&0\\ \end{bmatrix}\right)=\det \left(\begin{bmatrix} 2I_r&0 \\ 0&I_{n-r}\\ \end{bmatrix}\right)=2^r\gt 0.$$ Thus $(I+E)$ is invertible. By [theorem 4 section 5.4](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4561315/861687), $(I+E)^{-1}=\frac{1}{2^r}\cdot \text{adj}(I+E)$. **Is my proof correct?**

Comment: It looks good to me, although, for it to be fully satisfying, you should calculate that adjoint.

Comment: It's correct, but you could've just looked at the spectrum $\rho(E)=\{0,1\}$.

Comment: @peterag I tired. It was too messy. In hindsight I shouldn’t have stop and observe inverse is $(I-\frac{1}{2}E)$.

Comment: @V.S.e.H. I don’t know anything about spectrum. You shall give some references to read.

Comment: It's the set of eigenvalues of $E$. Surely you have that covered in your book.

Comment: @user264745 for culture, (I hope I am right - someone please correct me if not) the term 'spectrum' for eigenvalues comes from the light 'spectrum' of elements, because the possible emitted frequencies correspond to the eigenvalues of a certain operator (the Hamiltonian - quantum mechanics)... The term also shows in another area of mathematics that seems quite remote from 'light spectrum' (algebraic geometry);  nonetheless, it has the same origin there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since that  $E$ is  an idempotent linear operator on $V$, we have:

$$E^2-E-2I=-2I$$

i.e. $$(I+E)(2I - E)=2I$$

hence $(I+E)^{-1}$ is equal to $\frac 12 (2I-E)$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Your proof is really neat and clever. Btw I tired to find inverse of $(I-E)$ by try and error. But I failed. After seeing the inverse I feel like I was so close.

Comment: @user264745 You are always WELCOME.